# При любых корректировках массива $data - $output возвращает NULL

Tags: php, curl, null, яндекс-доставка

Подскажите плз кто чем может. Требуется с помощью API яндекса получить список вариантов доставки (https://yandex.ru/dev/delivery-3/doc/dg/reference/put-delivery-options.html). Запрос осуществляю следующим образом:

```
$data = array(
    'senderId' => <senderId>,
    'to' => array(
        'location' => 'Калининград, Октябрьская, 11',
        'geoId' => 22,
        'postalCode' => '236006'
    ),
    'dimensions' => array(
        'length' => 5,
        'width' => 3,
        'height' => 5,
        'weight' => 5.2
    )
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.delivery.yandex.ru/delivery-options' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: OAuth <token>'
));

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ) );

$output = curl_exec( $curl );
```

При любых корректировках массива $data - $output возвращает NULL. Токен корректен 100%, этот этап пройден. Работал кто-нибудь с этим API ?

Comment: https проверку отключи, а без коректировки массива данных норм работает?

Comment: отключил, ничего не изменилось. Про $data написал к тому, что дело не в массиве, никак не возвращает. Единственное наблюдение - curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true) возвращает 504, поэтому поставили таймаут, а если заменить на curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"), то просто NULL

Comment: а в кабинете настроен 1 регион?

Comment: все гуд, curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); вместе с curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
так же не отрабатывал, отработал с 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
Спасибо!)